# React Native Geolocation for WebView

Tags: android, react-native, webview, geolocation

Basically in Native Android app for using google Maps API in `WebView` I do this: ([Full Article](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-enable-geolocation-in-a-webview-android/))

1. In AndroidManifest.xml :

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   ```
2. In Activity:

   ```
   public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
       @Override
       public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
               GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
           callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
       }
   }
   ```
3. and finally in onCreate method:

   ```
   mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
   mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
   ```

I am trying to find an exact equivalent in React-Native WebView.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I figured it out.
Just putting granting permission in AndroidManifest.xml was enough

Comment: what about ios ?

Comment: for iOS I think you'll have to do more than just adding permission. Have you tried following the official documentation?